# Access denied for user 'User_so'@'10.64.0.148' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I am using a framework in java called: cuba-studio. 
When I try to make a jdbc connection to my mysql server, I get following exception:

```
Access denied for user 'User_so'@'10.64.0.148' (using password: YES)
```

My DatabaseURL is: `jdbc:mysql://instanceofCloud:3306/TEST`

Database user is: `User_so` 
which is the schema owner.

Does anybody have an idea, why this problem occurs?

EDIT: I use a cloud for mysql, I only have the roles: read/write, read, schema-owner

Thanks a lot

Comment: Because User_so has no access to the database named TEST **or** you have the wrong password.

Comment: but I can make a connection with Mysql workbench with the database user and there is this Test database too..

Answer (score 1):

Can you try doing this?

```
CREATE USER 'User_so'@'10.64.0.148' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON database.* TO 'User_so'@'10.64.0.148';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

As @nos has already mentioned, These SQL statements need to be run as a MySQL user that are allowed to grant further privileges.

Try logging into the MySQL instance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, 

I try to make this command but I get this problem: 

11:18:53 CREATE USER 'User_so'@'10.64.0.148' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation 0.172 sec

Comment: @Schaumkuesschen You need to run these SQL statements as a MySQL user that are allowed to grant further privileges.

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer, the problem is, I use a mysql server of cloud, means, I only have the roles: write/read, read and schema owner, I have no possibility to make further privileges, because I have no possibility to do so as admin :( 

So it still dont work..do you have any hint for me? Thanks a lot